# Change label shipping-calculator-button

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I just would like to change the label or name of the shipping-calculator-button in the shopping cart of WordPress.

I try with this code

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'woocomerce_text_strings', 20, 3 );  

function woocomerce_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {            
   switch ( $translated_text ) {            
       case 'shipping calculator' :        
            $translated_text = __( 'Découvrez nos modes de livraison', 'woocommerce' );        
            break;    
   }        
   return $translated_text;             
}
```

Comment: After matching case only return the text `return 'Découvrez nos modes de livraison';`. No need for break or setting to a variable. I think, you need to switch for `$text` and not `$translated_text`.

Comment: Hi Markus,
Thanks for your help ! I add this but it's doesn't work. I think i don"t call the good variable

add_filter( 'gettext', 'woocomerce_text_strings', 20, 3 );        
function woocomerce_text_strings( $text, $text, $domain ) {            
       switch ( $text ) {            
            case 'shipping calculator' :        
                $text = __( 'Découvrez nos modes de livraison', 'woocommerce' );        
                break;    
        }        
        return $text;             
}